# How to secure DICOM images

Tags: encryption

I am working on securing DICOM medical images, and the proposed approach is to use selective image encryption based on a segmented Region Of Interest (ROI) and Region Of Background (ROB) of the DICOM image. However, I could not find the answers to the following questions, which are:

1. Why we need to encrypt DICOM images' pixel data if the DICOM provides mechanisms to encrypt the DICOM header data (patient and clinical information) using AES? As I found many researchers encrypt DICOM images' pixel data in the literature.
2. Does the PACS system have any requirements to have a readable DICOM image format, even if it is encrypted?
3. Which of the following two scenarios can be applied? Why? Are both applicable to the PACS system? what's the difference?

   - The complete encryption of the DICOM file (image pixel data + metadata (header data))
   - Encrypting only the pixel data (where will appear as distorted image) which preserves the header information (codec information) of the encrypted image.

Comment: I think you'd need to ask the makers of your PACS system for specific requirements, or your local information governance team if this is a business requirement not a technical requirement.

Comment: We can't answer (2). The answer to (1) is probably along the lines "while you don't know directly whose picture that is, given the image and possibly enough other samples you may still find out, so encrypt it anyways".

Comment: On this site, there are plenty of experts in cryptography, but not many who know about medical images. Could you explain a bit about what the images represent, why one would want to separate it into regions, and who is encrypting the images in what context?

Comment: @Gilles Actually, I've done the encryption part based on a brief literature review. In which I've used pixel segmentation to extract ROI and ROB, then encrypt ROI using AES and ROB using XOR. However, when I've been asked about the motivation of doing it in this way I could not find the answer, simply because encrypting the whole file seems to be easier, this is why I believe that there are some PACS system requirements that force researchers to do it in this way.